# Pull Data from another Sheet for one person

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a master Google sheet that lists Closed deals for a whole Sales Team. Then I have individual Google Sheets for each Sales Member. Is there an easy way to pull the data for each Sales Member from the Master sheet to their each individual sheet?

I have tried Vlookup, but it ends up repeating the same line over and over.

This is what the Master sheet looks like> [Master Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYFSt.png)

I would need to pull all of Cary's deals into his individual Spreadsheet.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have tried Vlookup, but it ends up repeating the same line over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see the column and row numbers of your spreadsheet, I created a sample spreadsheet.  Sheet1 looks like this:

[image: Sample SS]

Quite simply, you can use a FILTER formula like so:

> =FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A="**John**")

The formula is saying, return all rows in columns A and B (not including the headers) on Sheet1 where the name in column A is "John".  Just change the name to match the individual being searched.

You may wish to do this by referencing a cell containing the individual's name, making it easier to just paste the same formula into different sheets and return the results for each person.

One easy way to set this up is to create a dropdown (cell A2 in my example) that pulls from the name column on the original sheet.  In the case of my spreadsheet, it pulls from the names in Sheet1!A2:A:

[image: Data Validation]
[image: Dropdown]

Then in another cell (cell C2 in my example), use the same `FILTER` formula. except with a cell reference instead of the actual name:

> =FILTER(Sheet1!$A$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=A2)

The formula is saying, return all rows in columns A and B (not including the headers) on Sheet1 where the name in column A matches the name in the dropdown in A2 of this sheet.

Then you can just copy those cells and paste them into each separate sheet.  Then select the name in the dropdown according to which individual the sheet corresponds.

Here are the results:

[image: Sample Results]

If there are more columns of data for each individual, (as it appears there is in your screenshot) then change the column B in the formula to the appropriate column letter.

Comment: Did this help you with what you were trying to achieve?